# Calling C++/CLI Method with System::DateTime parameter requires 'ValueType' as a parameter?

Tags: c#, datetime, c++-cli, types

I'm attempting to call a method written in C++/CLI from C#. The C++/CLI code is used to update a `TIMESTAMP` column in an Oracle database, given a record ID and the `System::DateTime` object which is the .NET compatible data type for Oracle's `TIMESTAMP` type.

The method I am calling has the following prototype:

```
bool ChangeJobUpdateDate (int jobIdIn, System::DateTime^ updateDateIn)
```

I've added a reference to this DLL project in a test project that I made; I'm writing the tests in C#. However, when I try to call this method from the C# unit test project, the function appears to have the following method declaration (via intellisense):

```
bool ChangeJobUpdateDate (int jobIdIn, ValueType updateDateIn)
```

I'm admittedly not that familiar with C++/CLI, so is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I suspect it's because you're using `DateTime^` instead of just `DateTime`. It's a value type, so why are you trying to use a reference?

C# doesn't have any way of representing the boxed reference type associated with a value type, so the best it can do is `ValueType` - I *suspect* that's what's happening, although I can't say for sure due to my lack of experience with C++. Try just `DateTime` and see how that looks...

Comment: That was it! Looks like I will need to spend some more time reading up on the meaning of these ^%&*ing symbols. Thanks! :)

Comment: That's pretty much it. C++/CLI actually does encode the real type of the value into the signature - in this case, in IL, the complete type would be: `class [mscorlib]System.ValueType modopt([mscorlib]System.DateTime) modopt([mscorlib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.IsBoxed)` - which is how C++/CLI compiler later knows the correct type and will do proper typechecking - but C# just ignores all `modopt`'s and treats it as a plain `ValueType`.

Comment: @Pavel: Thanks for the detail. I was really just making an educated guess. Feel free to edit all this goodness into my answer - or add your own :)